# Cuando oprimo un input de tipo submit no hace nada

Tags: html, css

Hice este form para una web que por el momento solo use HTML y CSS. Cuando lo terminé, llene los datos del form y oprimí el botón, pero este no realizaba ninguna acción (Cuando tengo entendido que por defecto debería limpiar los datos ingresados, ya que no está vinculado a ningún archivo .js)

```html
<section class="section-calc">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="container-input">
      <h2 class="title-calc">Calculadora de Percentiles</h2>
      <select id="sexo" class="input-calc">
        <option class="select-opt" value="niñas">Femenino</option>
        <option class="select-opt" value="niños">Masculino</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="estatura" class="input-calc" placeholder="Estatura (cm)">
      <input type="text" id="peso" class="input-calc" placeholder="Peso (kg)">
      <input type="date" id="date" class="input-calc" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento">
      <input type="submit" id="btn-calc" value="Calcular">
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Si resetea todo lo que tienen los campos, lo probé con **.php** y **.html**

Comment: No hace nada porque no le estás indicando que haga algo... ¿Tienes algún código JS?...

Comment: Eso que describes es un comportamiento resultante del estándar (por defecto un form envía un GET y el destino es él mismo). No es que _se limpie_ sino que la página se recarga porque hay un mensaje GET donde la página se llama a sí misma. Ahora, si te siguen saliendo los campos diligenciados, puede ser cosa de tu navegador que "se pasa de astuto".

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento de un botón submit asociado a un form sin action, por defecto hace un GET y el "limpiar campos" es que al hacer un GET vuelve a acceder a la dirección, luego depende si tienes valores por defecto, si los estás recuperando de algún servicio u otra cosa. ¿Seguro que no tienes ningún JS capturando el evento submit genérico? Revisa la consola del explorador para ver si está dando un error por otro motivo

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. Mira [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).